# JavaScript Прокрутить страницу вниз

Tags: javascript

Как прокрутить веб страницу вниз при помощи чистого java script. Страница строится динамически по мере прокрутки вниз. Я набросал код, который внизу, но есть проблема - document.body.scrollHeight не изменяется. Т.е. выполняется прокрутка один раз. Поэтому и пляски с задержкой на 100 миллисекунд, думал, что нужно время для подзагрузки. Но не помогает даже приостановка по alert.

```
function scrollToEndPage(height, attempt) {
alert("hight:" + height + " scrollHeight:" + document.body.scrollHeight + " att:" + attempt  );

if (height != document.body.scrollHeight)
{
    height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    window.scrollTo(0, height);
    attempt++;

    setTimeout(scrollToEndPage( height, attempt ), 100);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
var height = 15;
var attempt = 4;
var intS = 0;
function scrollToEndPage() {
console.log("hight:" + height + " scrollHeight:" + document.body.scrollHeight + " att:" + attempt  );

if (height < document.body.scrollHeight)
{
    //height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    window.scrollTo(0, height);
    attempt++;
    height = parseInt(height) + attempt;
}
esle
{
    clearInterval(intS);
}
}
intS = setInterval(scrollToEndPage,100);
```

Comment: Ответ в принципе работает. Только параметр attempt ты неправильно понял - это просто подсчет попыток - counter. В общем мой вариант выглядит так: var height = 0;
var attempt = 0;
var intS = 0;
function scrollToEndPage() {
console.log("height:" + height + " scrollHeight:" + document.body.scrollHeight + " att:" + attempt  );
 if (height < document.body.scrollHeight)
 {
  height = document.body.scrollHeight;
  window.scrollTo(0, height);
  attempt++;
 }
 else
 {
  clearInterval(intS);
 }
}
intS = setInterval(scrollToEndPage,5000);

Comment: Хороший пример :)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось реализовать и через setTimeout. 
Нельзя так:

```
setTimeout(scrollToEndPage( height, attempt ) }, 100);
```

Нужно:

```
setTimeout(function() {scrollToEndPage( height, attempt ) }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте при загрузке и каждом обновлении страницы следующий код:

```
el.scrollTop = Math.ceil(el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight);
```

Где el - это страница или элемент, где требуется все промотать вниз, а округление нужно для точности позиционирования на экранах с высоким разрешением. scrollHeight запрашиваем каждый раз заново, когда произошло обновление страницы.